# Поиск суммы в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, суммирование

Есть лог файл в формате txt, который постоянно обновляется. И среди строк этого файла проскакивает шаблонное сообщение содержащее в себе два числа. Как реализовать чтение именно этих двух чисел и запись их в переменные.
К примеру

```
[I] [22:50:14] [01:50:14] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  >> �������������� �� ��� �������� �����
[I] [22:50:19] [01:50:18] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  ������ ������: 530 + 797
[I] [22:50:19] [01:50:18] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  ��� ������ ����� ������, �������� ����� � ���������� 1��.
```

То есть нужно выделить среди строк 530+797, и записать сумму в переменную.

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

a = ["[I] [22:50:14] [01:50:14] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  >> �������������� �� ��� �������� �����",
"[I] [22:50:19] [01:50:18] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  ������ ������: 530 + 797",
"[I] [22:50:19] [01:50:18] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]  ��� ������ ����� ������, �������� ����� � ���������� 1��."]

for i in a:
    res = re.findall(r': (\d+) \+ (\d+)$', i)    
    if res:
        print(sum(map(int, *res)))

#1327
```

Comment: Всё так, вот только не стоит читать логи целиком в память. Чревато. Анализируйте построчно, желательно с сохранением последней позиции в конфиге и при последующем запуске анализатора - с проверкой совпадения хеша последней строки с сохраненным и продолжением. Или переходом к началу, если лог отротировали...

Comment: Как автор вопроса будет читать логи - это отдельный разговор. Ответ был дан на конкретный вопрос, а ваш комментарий - не по адресу.

Answer (score 0):

Как я заметил уважаемому @strawdog в комментариях к его ответу, чтение логов целиком в память - нехорошо, лучше - построчно. Да и код в этом случае попроще для понимания получается:

```
import re

# Компилируем regex перед использованием в цикле - экономим время
r_pattern = re.compile(': (\d+) \+ (\d+)$')

# Не забываем указать правильную кодировку файла лога
with open('test.log','rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline() # читаем построчно
        if not line: break 

        match = re.search(r_pattern, line) # Ищем
        if match:
            # И, найдя, подсчитываем
            value = int(match.group(1)) + int(match.group(2))
            print(value)
```